# How to separate only the numbers out to two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to separate the following column to two columns
the one before @ and the one after @ 
Its okay if I need to write my own function as long as not hard coding

```
12 @ 300
24 @ 524
1 @ 788
412 @ 63
014 @ 786
16 @ 8063
```

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Please be more specific about the  numbers are you looking to get: should it be {`12`, `24`, `1`, ...}? Maybe {`300`, `524`, `788`,...}? Or {`12300`, `24524`, `1788`,...}? Or even {`12`, `24`, `1`, ..., `300`, `524`, `788`,...}

Comment: can you find a char in a string? can you take substring before/after certain position? can you remove leading/tailing spaces from a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT RTRIM(LEFT(column1, CHARINDEX('@', column1) - 1)) number1,
       LTRIM(RIGHT(column1, LEN(column1) - CHARINDEX('@', column1))) number2
  FROM table1
```

Output:

```
| NUMBER1 | NUMBER2 |
|---------|---------|
|      12 |     300 |
|      24 |     524 |
|       1 |     788 |
|     412 |      63 |
|     014 |     786 |
|      16 |    8063 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6fd8a/8)** demo

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what SQL flavor you are using but in most applications the following will work:

```
    select
       substr('yourString',1,index('yourString','@') - 1) as col1,
       substr('yourString',index('yourString','@') + 1) as col12,
    from
       yourTable
    ;
```

The above code is written for teradata sql server but most applications have the same string functions.

Hope this helps.